# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Tags: c#

I am creating a user login page using C#.
I am getting this following error:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

My code:

```cs
private async void _saveButton_Clicked(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
    db.CreateTable<User>();

    var maxPk = db.Table<User>().OrderByDescending(c =>c.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    User user = new User()
    {
        Id = (maxPk == null ? 1 : maxPk.Id +1), //error here
        Email = _emailEntry.Text,
        Password = _passwordEntry.Text
    };

    db.Insert(user);
    await DisplayAlert(null, user.Email + "Saved", "Ok");
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Editing to add datatypes declared

```cs
[PrimaryKey]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You cannot add an int to an object.

Comment: Please show how the type `User` is declared. Either `Id` is not declared as `int` (or `long` or something), or `Email` is not declared as string. Well, the error message even tells you _where_ the error occurs.

Comment: Also, `SQLiteConnection` is `IDisposable` but you never seem to dispose it.

Comment: id is declared int, email is string. User is the table name created

Comment: Yet another problem here is possible concurrency issue where two parallel requests both ask for the current max ID and both add 1 and then both try to insert a new record with the same ID. The first succeeds the other fails. Please consider declaring your ID as `primary key autoincrement`.

Comment: Which actual line causes the compiler error?

Comment: edited line which shows compile error

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my error:

Id = (maxPk == null ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(maxPk.Id) +1),

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
var maxPk = db.Table<User>().OrderByDescending(c =>c.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

but what you really wanted is

```
var maxPk = db.Table<User>().OrderByDescending(c =>c.Id)
      .Select( c => c.Id ).FirstOrDefault();
```

(*note that the default here for the key type is `0`, you'd have to also tweak your `if` accordingly*)

which makes `maxPk` to be your key rather than the `User` object.

Please, however, carefully follow other comments, too.